# HTML element's margins are not applied in PDF after conversion with iTextSharp

Tags: html, css, itext

I am using iTextSharp library for HTML to PDF conversion.
Could you suggest why following HTML+CSS is not converted to PDF properly? Looks like elements margins are not applied at all…Text is stuck to the left. Browser (Chrome) centers it fine.

---

CSS:

```
  #sgh-mainC {
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PDS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sgh-mainC">
        text that should be centered
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

C#:

```
 private void CreatePdf(string html, string css)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] bytes;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var doc = new Document())
                    {
                        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                        {
                            doc.Open();
                            var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
                            var msCss = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)));
                            cssResolver.AddCss(msCss);

                            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
                            htmlContext.AutoBookmark(false);
                            var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));

                            PdfWriterPipeline pdfPpl = new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer);
                            HtmlPipeline htmlPpl = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdfPpl);
                            CssResolverPipeline cssPpl = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPpl);

                            new XMLParser(new XMLWorker(cssPpl, true)).Parse(htmlStream);

                            doc.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    bytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
                if (File.Exists(FilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(FilePath);
                }
                var file = File.Create(FilePath);
                file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //TODO log errror
            }
        }
```

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: 1. Are you using `HTMLWorker`? If so, then you should know that `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned ages ago and the CSS isn't supported in `HTMWorker`. 2. Are you using XML Worker? If so, be aware that not all CSS values are supported, but if you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), someone can take a look at it.

Comment: XMLWorker as you can see. I've added method I am using to the post. Will do SSCCE later. But this is pretty much everything...

Answer (score 1):

This questions is a bit old, however in case anyone else stumbles across this post...

It appears there is a very limited set of CSS that iTextSharp actually supports. You can find it at http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm